# My right sidebar is not working properly like left sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML/CSS on my own, most of the time I get an error on every line I write.
I don't know why my right side bar is not correctly placed like the left one. Please take a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn2Lqv6n/).

```
<div class="bo">
       <div class="left">
         <div class="lside">
           <div class="lhead"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
      <div class="pbo">
         <div class="post">
            <div class="hpost">
                <img src="1016949_702659679791359_6170947506430480265_n.jpg" height=50 width=50 />
     <p>VigneshWarar  </p>

             </div>


          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="right">
         <div class="rside"></div>
       </div>

   </div>
```

CSS

```
.bo{
    top:0px;
    width:1150px;
    background: #FAFAFA;


   }
    .pbo{
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    height:500px;



}
.post{
    height: 390px;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    top: 0px;



}
.hpost{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top:none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;

}
.hpost p{
    margin-left: 56px;
    margin-top: -49px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.lside{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background:#FF0000;
    border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;


}
.lhead{
    height: 40px;

}
.rside{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background:#0000FF;
    border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
    margin-top: inherit;

}
```

Comment: Use the same rules that you used in `left sidebar` to `right side`

Comment: I can find any styling for <dig class="right">?

Comment: that was thing i done But it is displaying under the post div

Comment: rside refers to to right div

Comment: just put the div.right behind div.left... example following..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit fuzzy but this does the trick..more information is on his way...

**edit:**  so say it like this: if you float an element he will float from hes relative position.

Example: if a div is on relative: 500px (top), 40px (left) and you float the div to right: he will float to relative: 500px (top) 0px (right). To solve this you need to place this div on relative: 0px (top).You can achieve this by *a)* position the element to `top: 0px` or *b)* place the div in html on first line or wherever he reach relative: 0px(top).

i also position the element with your name in it instead of:

```
  margin-left: 56px;
  margin-top: -49px;
```

to:

```
.hpost {
   ...
   position: relative;
}
.hpost p {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
}
```

If you do not understand this, feel free to contact me.

I also edit your css-code to a more readable code (for me)

```css
.bo {
  width: 1150px;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

.pbo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  /*T0*/
}

.post {
  height: 390px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid rgb(232, 232, 232);
}

.hpost {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(232, 232, 232);
  position: relative;
}

.hpost p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 192, 203);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
}

.lside,
.rside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(225, 232, 237);
}

.lside {
  float: left;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.lhead, .rhead {
  height: 40px;
}

.rside {
  float: right;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="bo">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="lside">
      <div class="lhead">Left to Left</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="rside">
      <div class="rhead">Right to Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pbo">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="hpost">
        <img src="1016949_702659679791359_6170947506430480265_n.jpg" height=50 width=50>
        <!-- not /> this is HTML not XML markup -->
        <p>VigneshWarar</p>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: @vigneshwarar my answer is finished, take a look at it  :-) Thanks for accepting. if you have any question.. please feel free to contact me.